# webpack merge definePlugin process.env.NODE_ENV undefined

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack-merge with different webpack.config files.
I am trying to pass the node_env (or any other variabels);

How can I access the process env variable from the webpack.common.js file?

This is the webpack.prd.config.js file:

```
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                "NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("production")
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

This is the webpack.common.js file:

```
console.log("Environment: " + process.env.NODE_ENV);

module.exports = {
    entry: {
    ...
```

The 'process.env.NODE_ENV' variable is always undefined.

Comment: If I recall correctly, `process.env.<name>` refers to environmental variables for the current process. If you're on Mac or Linux try typing `export NODE_ENV=production`, then running your build process and see whether the variable is still undefined

Comment: I'm on windows in asn ASP.NET core application. How can I pass variabels from the webpack.prd.config.js to the webpack.common.js file? It doesn't need to be the NODE_ENV variable.

Comment: I've worked with neither webpack nor ASP.NET, so my environment variable guess is the best I can give you, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

I just realized that webpack -p does not send the value of `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `webapck.conf.js`

I solve this headache by

```
"scripts": {
    "prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && webpack -p",
  },
```

Just make sure that when you try to compare them just add space at the end of production

```
var isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production ";
```

Answer (score 2):

`DefinePlugin` only add a global object to your code (what you send to webpack) not webpack's config.

So if you want to `NODE_ENV` in your webpack config, you must export it first:

```
export NODE_ENV=production
webpack ....
```

or

```
NODE_ENV=production webpack ...
```